# Recursive function to find user controls in a generic type

Tags: c#, list, generics, recursion

This is my code

```
    private void FindControls<T>(Control control, List<T> list)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c != null)
            {
                if (c is T)
                {
                    list.Add(c);  //<-- Problem is here
                }
                else
                {
                    FindControls<T>(c, list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the message

> "The best overloaded match for
>   'System.Collection.Generic.List.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments"

This is another method to find the specific control

```
    private void MyMethod(Employee e)
    {
        List<MyUserControlType> employees = new List<MyUserControlType>();
        this.FindControls<MyUserControlType>(this.MyControlRoot, employees);
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

I want to return a list of controls of type MyUserControlType which doesn't inherit from type Control. Inherits from UserControl

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you have to cast C to T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can cast it using `as` operator like

```
            if (c is T)
            {
                list.Add((c as T));  //<-- Problem is here
            }
```

That constraint can be placed by modifying your method definition

```
private void FindControls<T>(Control control, List<T> list) where T : class
{
```

(OR) as pointed by @Ivan in comment you can cast it directly using the cast operator which won't require you to place the generic constraint in method

```
            if (c is T)
            {
                list.Add((T)c);  //<-- Problem is here
            }
```

Comment: I already tried that but I get: "The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint"

Comment: Why `as T` and not cast `(T)`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, make sense but since it's under condition `if(c is T)` casting it using `as` would not be issue..

Comment: I know it's safe:) I was just curious why you choose that one at the first place, which in turn required you to add constraint. While the other would work w/o constraint.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Umm, that's what came in mind while posting the answer but yes nice point and thank you. Included that.